# Where to place ads on a blog when viewed by mobile?

Tags: website-design, mobile, layout, advertisement

When a blog is read on computer with a full screen we can show the viewer ads on the right and left without being too intrusive. The user can still read the blog post unhampered.

But what about mobile? Assuming the user is holding a phone in portrait mode (-upright), is there any way to show ads in a (relatively) unobtrusive way?

Answer (score 1):

It's commonly used between the pharagraphs by most of the publishers applying as a best practice I realized and implemented till now. It depends the medium or the type of blog but the end/beginning seperation of two different or related blog/article is also a good choice.

PS: It's not depending to any research result but as an experince I got from different examples in various situations, placing the advertisement to the relatively not attractive part for readers make your blog more tolerated...